Managing Azure DevOps PATs with non-interactive login
I'm able to manage the Azure DevOps Personal Access Tokens through the REST API if the interactive logon is enabled for the account. However, my scope is to disable the interactive logon. I've tried with an App Registration/Service Principal, but I haven't been able to, it seems that Microsoft doesn't allow managing PATs through this?
Is managing PATs with non-interactive sign in possible?
Tried to create a new PAT while logged in with a service pricipal, ended up with an unclear error.

Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/concept-sign-ins#what-are-the-types-of-sign-in-logs


I've tried with an App Registration/Service Principal, but I haven't been able to, it seems that Microsoft doesn't allow managing PATs through this? Is managing PATs with non-interactive sign in possible?

You can't use service principals to create or revoke PATs directly. It's mentioned in doc:

But you can use service principal to grant Microsoft Entra tokens, and use the token with PAT Lifecycle Management API to create the PAT.
You can find the details steps in my answer here and similar answer here.
Please also check official doc Manage personal access tokens (PATs) using REST API for the details.

Hi Wade, thanks a lot for your answer!
I see this method uses a browser to get a code. Do I need to do this everytime?
I'm asking because my intention is to create a full non-interactive Powershell script to use within an Automation Account.

Although you don't need to do everytime, but access tokens are short lived. Typically we will use refresh token to refresh access token after they expire.  The lifetimes of refresh tokens are relatively long(90days). You can check my another answer about refresh token and doc here. You can not create a full non-interactive powershell script.
